# Deleting rows with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hypothetically, if I have 6 rows that meet a certain criteria ..

(ie, `WHERE First = 'Bob' AND Middle = 'J' AND Last = 'Dole'`)

..and I do a `DELETE FROM table WHERE First = 'Bob' AND Middle = 'J' AND Last = 'Dole' LIMIT 5`..

Which 5 rows will be deleted first?

My assumption is that it would delete the rows with the lowest primary key first, is this correct?

Comment: your question is interesting... but may I ask: why are you concerned with the order of row deletion? you are deleting all the rows anyway

Comment: @Barranka Would this still delete all rows if there are 6 rows and I add a LiMIT 5 clause to the query?

Comment: I've edited my answer to cover that approach: as there is really no way to predict the *default order* of deletion, you *should* specify the order using `order by`, and then, if you need, use `limit` to delete the first `n` rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default SQL will delete rows from top to bottom in your database, inshort first 5 records in the table, so if you want, you can ORDER them first using `ORDER BY` clause with `ASC` or `DESC`

Comment: From top to bottom, you mean by default it uses DESC?

Comment: @cream unless and until you don't specify the search criteria, it will delete first 5 from db

Comment: I'm confused, the first 5 would be going in ASC order, the verbiage "from top to bottom" implies DESC, can you clarify?

Comment: @cream SQL do not sort records in ASC or DESC by default, it can be random too, you need to specify the criteria you need using ASC or DESC, I was not sure, so I made a table with records and deleted, without using `ORDER BY` clause, it deletes first 5 records from the beginning

Comment: It should be made clear: In (non-DBMS-specific) SQL, rows *have no ordering* by default -- and without one, the concept of the "first 5 rows" becomes highly implementation-specific.  If you want an order, specify it.  MySQL may define the order, but it'd still be wiser to specify an order yourself if you want a particular one.

Comment: @cHao Ya, what if user switches db later, better use `ORDER BY` to be specific

Comment: @Mr.Alien Can I ask you a reference that mentions the "default" sql behavior you mention in your answer?

Comment: @Barranka I didn't referenced anything, I tested locally, did you read my comment?

Answer (score 1):

Better you use something like this

```
Delete from table where id in 
(select id from table where First = 'Bob' AND Middle = 'J' 
                         AND Last = 'Dole' order by id asc)
```

now change asc to dsc  and you can be sure how it works .

thanks

Comment: Cool! Unfortunately I already ran the script using the SQL posted above, I'm just trying to figure out if the remaining records are the ones with the highest id or the lowest. In the future I will definitely do this though.

Comment: I don't think this forces any order for the delete operation... just is another way to filter the data (and I think is more inefficient, since `in` conditions force the server to run the subquery once for every row in the table)

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that there's not any `ORDER BY` clause (which is mostly irrelevant anyway on a `DELETE` operation), there's no way to tell *exactly* the order on which the rows are deleted.

Although your assumption of *lowest primary key go first*  may sound valid, the real order may depend on the indexes used to track down the rows, given the `WHERE` condition.

The only way you can really predict the order of row deletion is deleting rows one-by-one, using a stored procedure or a program written on another language. The algorithm would be like this (as agnostic as I can be):

```
strSQL = "select * 
          from yourTable 
          where First = 'Bob' and Middle = 'J' and Last = 'Dole' 
          order by Id"
rowSet = fetch_query(strSQL)
for each row in rowSet
    id = row.get(id)
    strSQL = concatenate("delete from yourTable where id=", id)
    execute_query(strSQL)
next row
```

---

After checking the reference manual ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html ), I found this:

> If the `DELETE` statement includes an `ORDER BY` clause, rows are deleted in the order specified by the clause. This is useful primarily in conjunction with `LIMIT`. For example, the following statement finds rows matching the `WHERE` clause, sorts them by `timestamp_column`, and deletes the first (oldest) one:
>
> `DELETE FROM somelog WHERE user = 'jcole'
>   ORDER BY timestamp_column LIMIT 1;`
>
> `ORDER BY` may also be useful in some cases to delete rows in an order required to avoid referential integrity violations.

From this I deduce that the only way to **really** be sure of the order of deletion is to include an `ORDER BY` clause in your `DELETE` statement.

Comment: This is sort of what I'm doing, I just didn't use the 'ORDER BY' in the initial query. I'm using PHP.

Comment: `ORDER BY` would actually be quite useful when combined with `LIMIT`.  Combining the two, `DELETE FROM table WHERE First = 'Bob'...etc ORDER BY id LIMIT 5` would delete the 5 records with the lowest `id`s.  That's probably the single most useful result of being able to say `ORDER BY` in a delete query, and the main reason it's allowed in the first place.